# sort multidimensional array on the basis of a field in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have multidemensional arrary as shown below in which I want to do sorting on the basis of `[name]` field in php.

```
Array
(
    [chicago] => Array
        (
            [community_name] => Chicago, IL
            [areas] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => HELLO WORLD.
                                )
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Hello
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Administration.
                                )
                        )
                )

        )

    [chicago-and-surrounding-areas] => Array
        (
            [community_name] => Chicago (and surrounding areas), IL
            [areas] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Carry.
                                )
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Bacteria.
                                )
                        )   
                )

        )

    [cambridge-chicago] => Array
        (
            [community_name] => Cambridge (Chicago), IL
            [areas] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Responsibility.
                                )
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Bacteria.
                                )
                        )   
                )

        )

)
```

This is what I want to achieve:

```
Array
(
    [chicago] => Array
        (
            [community_name] => Chicago, IL
            [areas] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Administration
                                )
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Hello
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => HELLO WORLD.
                                )
                        )
                )

        )

    [chicago-and-surrounding-areas] => Array
        (
            [community_name] => Chicago (and surrounding areas), IL
            [areas] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Bacteria.
                                )
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Carry.
                                )
                        )   
                )

        )

    [cambridge-chicago] => Array
        (
            [community_name] => Cambridge (Chicago), IL
            [areas] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Bacteria.
                                )
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Responsibility.
                                )
                        )   
                )

        )

)
```

This is what I have tried but I think more need to be done.

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a["name"] == $b["name"]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a["name"] < $b["name"]) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($response,"cmp");
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the php code above so that it sorts an array on the basis of `name` field. With my php code above its not sorting anything. It is just printing the input as it is.

Comment: If $response is your array, its elements have no 'name' key, their keys are 'comunity...', 'area', etc

Comment: Maybe you mean `foreach($response as $town){ usort($town['areas'] , 'cmp' ); }` or something like that? Your cmp function should also compare `$a['name'][0]==$b['name'][0]`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example, you're actually trying to sort the `areas` sub-array, rather than the whole parent array. As such you'll need to loop through each sub-array in turn and sort them separately.

```
$array = [
    'chicago' => [
        'community_name' => 'Chicago, IL',
        'areas' => [
            [
                'name' => ['HELLO WORLD.']
            ],
            [
                'name' => ['Hello'],
            ],
            [
                'name' => ['Administration.'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'chicago-and-surrounding-areas' => [
        'community_name' => 'Chicago (and surrounding areas), IL',
        'areas' => [
            [
                'name' => ['Carry.']
            ],
            [
                'name' => ['Bacteria.'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'cambridge-chicago' => [
        'community_name' => 'Cambridge (Chicago), IL',
        'areas' => [
            [
                'name' => ['Responsibility.']
            ],
            [
                'name' => ['Bacteria'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];

foreach ($array as &$locality) {
    usort($locality['areas'], function ($a, $b) {
        return $a['name'][0] <=> $b['name'][0];
    });
}

var_dump($array);
```

[Working example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/242eb8540bc36f13e61ec0273c907fb48618d2de)

Comment: I had a look at the code and it looks good. I am wondering why `HELLO WORLD` is coming before `Hello`. Thoughts ?

Comment: Because `H` is considered to have a lower value than `h`. `var_dump('H' < 'h'); // true`.

Comment: I have one more question. I have modified [fiddle](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/242eb8540bc36f13e61ec0273c907fb48618d2de) little bit. In it, I have added some accented character words. I am wondering what changes I need to make in the code in the fiddle so that it ignores accented characters while sorting. In the o/p, `Aṕple` should come before `Avocados`.

Comment: You could use the `iconv()` function to convert the character encoding. See this [example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bd98bc4633d528be012d90a206dca761628aa421).

Comment: In the [fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6d67caeecb7bf3c9651eb0da840a43bb4202778c), `Câble-Axion Digitel, Inc.` should come before `Covit Communications Inc.` ?

Comment: No, but will try another character set definitely. I am wondering why `Covit Communications Inc.` is coming before  `Câble-Axion Digitel, Inc.`.

Comment: Because the character set doesn't recognise the `â` character. Try `ISO-8859-8`.

Comment: I tried another character set [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aaa2d918ad4b7fa750b5fbdb09a56ba7a2cdc076)

Comment: Hi, its working now but is it gonna work in all cases ?

Comment: That depends entirely on the characters you're using. UTF-8 (what it was) would have worked with all characters. You're now using a subset of latin characters.

Comment: I have one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63691611/how-to-allow-the-2nd-user-to-take-over-when-the-1st-user-is-logged-in). It's not similar. I am wondering if you can have a look.